# Can't add Apple Developer Account on Visual Studio

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac, apple-developer-account

I updated VS 2019 to 8.3.8 (build 8) version on Mac Catalina 10.15.1

After that update, I can't add Apple Developer Account, I get this error:

[image: Error shown]

I can login in Apple portal and Apple Developer Portal with this account. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved installing VS version 8.3.10.2